# Some apps don't open in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04

Is it just me, or some apps don't open in Ubuntu 19.04? Apps like mysql workbench, wps-office, or even plank. Is it because Ubuntu 19.04 is not LTS?

EDIT:

For plank, I got an error like this:

```
plank
[CRITICAL 18:44:09.088007] [AbstractMain:257] Only X11 environments 
are supported.
```

Comment: It is quite hard to say what's going wrong from such a little info. But just because 19.04 is *non-LTS*, it doesn't mean apps should fail. Try running some problematic apps from a Terminal, then **[edit]** your question and add the error messages.

Comment: LTS stands for Long-Term-Support which effects only the length of time support is offered for official packages. Plank for example is in the repos (https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/plank) , however some 3rd party sources only offer LTS support to reduce workload on themselves.

Comment: If the behavior is reproducible on stock 19.04 (try a LiveUSB), then please file a bug report with sufficient detail for a bug triager to consistently reproduce the issue on their test system. Unreported bugs don't get fixed.

Comment: In addition to @user535733's comment I'd add that if the app is a snap package (e.g.wps-office) there may be a way to fix it so that it opens correctly. Unfortunately the way to fix it is not general, it is specific to each app. For example you may need to track down the location of the desktop launcher for that app and edit it and then it will launch correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with

```
loginctl show-session -p Type
```

or

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

or

```
inxi -Fxz
```

what environment you have running.  Any of them should show Wayland or X11.

- If Wayland you need to switch to an evironment that is X11.
- If it is not set you can set `XDG_SESSION_TYPE` to `X11` and it will all work again.

Comment: I thought 19.04 didn't have wayland by default?

Comment: Correct but it can be installed. It is more likely XDG_SESSION_TYPE is not set to X11.

Comment: @Rinzwind it did show me wayland when I ran "echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE". How do I set it to X11?

Comment: Log out and pick the option at the login screen. Ubuntu with xorg it is probably called.

Comment: @Rinzwind it worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your environment is X11 and still some applications aren't running, check if gedit is there cause there can be some issues with gnome.
So run this command `sudo apt install gnome`.

I got this answer here https://forum.level1techs.com/t/ubuntu-18-10-some-apps-not-launching/136058